# Nginx, FastCGI and Django connection refused error

Tags: django, nginx, fastcgi

I've setup nginx, fastcgi and django. The run my django project through fastcgi using:

```
python26 manage.py runfcgi host=127.0.0.1 port=8080 --settings=settings
```

When I visit http://127.0.0.1 I can see the normal django 404 since I haven't setup everything on my django project aside from the admin. So I tried visinting http://127.0.0.1/admin and it returns a 502 bad gateway error.

I checked the logs and here's what I've found. Anybody who knows what's causing this error?

```
    2010/10/15 23:09:34 [error] 4796#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:8080", host: "localhost"
2010/10/15 23:09:34 [error] 4796#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flup/server/fcgi_base.py", line 574, in run
    protocolStatus, appStatus = self.server.handler(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flup/server/fcgi_base.py", line 1159, in handler
    result = self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 245, in __call__
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py", line 36, in process_response
    request.session.save()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 56, in save
    session_key = self.session_key,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 152, in _get_session_key
    self._session_key = self._get_new_session_key()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 144, in _get_new_session_key
    if not self.exists(session_key):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 29, in exists
    Session.objects.get(session_key=session_key)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 132, in get
    return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 336, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 81, in __len__
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 269, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 672, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 726, in execute_sql
    cursor =
```

BTW I'm running nginx07 and django1.2.

UPDATE:

Here's my nginx configs:

```
    user  apache apache;

worker_processes  4;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error_log info;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    use epoll;
}

http {
    include            /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type    application/octet-stream;

    log_format main
        '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
            '"$request" $status $bytes_sent '
        '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
        '"$gzip_ratio"';

    client_header_timeout    10m;
    client_body_timeout        10m;
    send_timeout            10m;

    connection_pool_size        256;
    client_header_buffer_size    1k;
    large_client_header_buffers    4 2k;
    request_pool_size            4k;

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length    1100;
    gzip_buffers    4 8k;
    gzip_types        text/plain;

    output_buffers    1 32k;
    postpone_output    1460;

    sendfile    on;
    tcp_nopush    on;
    tcp_nodelay    on;

    keepalive_timeout    75 20;

    ignore_invalid_headers    on;
    index index.html;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        location /site_media  {
            root /media/; # Notice this is the /media folder that we create above
        }
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js|mov) {
            access_log   off;
            expires      30d; 
        }
        location / {
            # host and port to fastcgi server
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
            fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH   $content_length;
            fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE     $content_type;
            fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING     $query_string;
            fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD   $request_method;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME      $server_name;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT      $server_port;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL  $server_protocol;

            fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        }
        access_log    /var/log/nginx/localhost.access_log main;
        error_log    /var/log/nginx/localhost.error_log;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show  app logs instead of nginx logs. Paste you nginx configs.

Comment: What do you mean by app logs? Sorry, I'm still new to this stuff. I updated my post to include my nginx configs.

Answer (score 0):

I can see from your logs that even connections for '/' is refused, so this has nothing to do with the admin.

Try using telnet to connect to localhost on the correct port and see if you can open a connection. I would guess that the daemon is not running.

You also removed the python traceback, which would be very helpful in determining why the process might have crashed.

Comment: Hi, I added the whole traceback. You're right, when I do telnet it returned connection refused. But I don't know why. Is there something wrong with my nginx configs?

Comment: No, if you cannot connect using telnet, there is nothing accepting connections. Check that your app is really running and listening on that port. Also, if the app is listening on 127.0.0.1, it will only accept connections from localhost, not from any external host.

Comment: I had another look at the traceback and it seems it crashes when it tries to save a session to the database. Are you using sqlite? Do the user running the process have permission to read and write the sqlite file as well as read and execute on the parent dir?